# Unable to dynamically add functional list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to dynamically populate the list, which should have the following structure:

```
<ul class="todo-list m-t small-list ui-sortable" id="myList">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="check-link">
            <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>
        </a>
        <span class="m-l-xs todo-completed">Buy a milk</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="check-link">
            <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> 
        </a>
        <span class="m-l-xs  todo-completed">Go to shop and find some products.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="check-link">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> 
        </a>
        <span class="m-l-xs">Send documents to Mike</span>
        <small class="label label-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
            1 mins
        </small>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="check-link">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
        </a>
        <span class="m-l-xs">Go to the doctor dr Smith</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="check-link">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> 
        </a>
        <span class="m-l-xs">Plan vacation</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The following procedure adds the items to the list but the items don't behave as they should:

```
function populateMyList(items){
    $("#myList").empty();
    items.forEach(function(listItem) {
        var strToAppend = '<li>' +
            '<a href="#" class="check-link"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> </a>' +
            '<span class="m-l-xs">' + listItem + '</span>' +
            '</li>';
        $("#myList").append(strToAppend);
        //$('#myList').listview('refresh');
    });
```

If the line `$('#myList').listview('refresh');` is included, the following error appears:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).listview is not a function

In case the line is commented, the items are populated but the checkboxes don't work.

Looking around for similar problems I noticed that some were solved by using different version of jQuery (I use 2.1.4). As the other items depend on jQuery version 2.1.4 I cannot switch to other version and I guess this is not the right way to solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to dynamically populate the list with all functionalities?

**Edit:**

Actually I wanted to modify [this](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0R5L90S) bootstrap template (TODO Small version list)

I tried to include all dependencies [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uxoqnpst/) and to run an example but it doesn't work

Comment: maybe listview is a member of jquery.ui or some other library? https://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/

Comment: _checkboxes don't work._ i can't see these in the list items.

Comment: Just a tip but only select your list once outside your foreach and reuse it. `var myList = $("#myList");` / `myList.append(...`

Comment: Post your code for the checkbox please or make a jsfiddle

Comment: @GeneR yes I think it's part of jquery-mobile

Comment: why are you removing and adding again all the items? http://jsfiddle.net/bq1xjxdL here  it works (except for the css). also you should `$.clone(true, true)` to retain event handlers and other stuff.

Comment: @Christophe I've added the links.

Comment: `.listview("refesh")` used only with jQuery-Mobile, which you aren't using. https://jsfiddle.net/uxoqnpst/1/

Comment: @NikoGamulin none of your resources you included in the jsfiddle works.